# Get Subtypes of VersionInfo

Tags: powershell

I would like to get few file attributes from Powershell command `Get-Item` or `Get-ItemProperty`

```
Get-Item -Path c:\windows\system32\gdi32.dll | Select Name, Length, VersionInfo.ProductVersion, VersionInfo.FileVersion, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime

Get-ItemProperty -Path c:\windows\system32\gdi32.dll -Name Name, Length, VersionInfo.ProductVersion, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime
```

Both of the commands does not give me `VersionInfo.ProductVersion`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass `VersionInfo.ProductVersion` as a parameter argument to a function, PowerShell interprets it as the string "VersionInfo.ProductVersion", and starts looking for a property with that *exact name*. But a `FileInfo` object doesn't have such a property, which is why it doesn't work.

You'll need a calculated property in order to grab the the property values of `VersionInfo`:

```
Get-Item ... |Select Name,Length,@{Name='ProductVersion';Expression={$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion}},@{Name='FileVersion';Expression={$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}},CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime
```

You can also prepare all the property names as an array ahead of time:

```
$ItemProperties = @(
    'Name'
    'Length'
    @{Name = 'ProductVersion'; Expression = {$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion}}
    @{Name = 'FileVersion'; Expression = {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}}
    'CreationTime'
    'LastAccessTime'
    'LastWriteTime'
)

Get-Item ... |Select $ItemProperties
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. That answers my question